# How to change plot properties of statsmodels qqplot? (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, statsmodels

So I am plotting a normal Q-Q plot using [statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot()](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot.html).

The module uses matplotlib.pyplot to create figure instance. It plots the graph well.

However, I would like to plot the markers with alpha=0.3.

Is there a way to do this?

Here is a sample of code:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test = np.random.normal(0,1, 1000)

sm.qqplot(test, line='45')
plt.show()
```

And the output figure:
[image: QQ Plot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`qqplot`](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot.html) returns a [`figure`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api) object which can be used to get the [`lines`](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api) which can then be modified using [`set_alpha`](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_alpha)

```
fig = sm.qqplot(test, line='45');

# Grab the lines with blue dots
dots = fig.findobj(lambda x: hasattr(x, 'get_color') and x.get_color() == 'b')

[d.set_alpha(0.3) for d in dots]
```

[image]

Obviously you have a bit of overlap of the dots so even though they have a low alpha value, where they are piled on top of one another they look to be more opaque.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.ProbPlot](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.ProbPlot.html#statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.ProbPlot) class which has [qqplot](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.ProbPlot.qqplot.html#statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.ProbPlot.qqplot) method to pass matplotlib [pyplot.plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) **kwargs.

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)

pp = sm.ProbPlot(test, fit=True)
qq = pp.qqplot(marker='.', markerfacecolor='k', markeredgecolor='k', alpha=0.3)
sm.qqline(qq.axes[0], line='45', fmt='k--')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, nice! Did not know about this.